# How do I relaunch terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal

When I open the terminal, it has showed:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Text was empty (or contained only whitespace)
```

and two options `profile preference` or `relaunch`

Answer (score 0):

If you have another profile for gnome terminal you can do the following: from hud or from `xterm` call `gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=profilename` where profile name is actual profile. Then you can access options to change your other , broken profile

Alternatively, enable showing hidden files and folders in file manager, and delete everything in  `/home/username/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/`, which is where your settings are stored. That will effectivelly restore everything to defaul